# Copy/paste not working while VNC Viewer is connected to a PC

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste, vnc-viewer

My copy/paste function stop working when I connect to a pc using VNC Viewer. This is throughout my own pc that it stops working and not just to the remote PC. Work again right after VNC is closed.
When I copy something (doesn't matter if it's on my PC, the VNC connected pc or a RDP connected pc) while VNC Viewer is connected to a PC I get random text when trying to copy a text.

Anybody else experienced this and possibly has a fix?